# Division Theorem in the integers adjoin square root of minus two

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Q. let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] = \{a + b\sqrt{-2} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Show that if $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}],$ $t\not = 0$ then there exists $r,q \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ s.t.$ s = tq + r$ where$N(r) < N(t)$

my attempt,
if we divide s by t:$\dfrac{s}{t} = m + n\sqrt{-2}$ where $ m,n \in \mathbb{Q}$

now we can define$q = q_1 + q_2\sqrt{-2} $where $q_1,q_2$ are the largest integers s.t. $q_1,q_2 \leq m,n$ then we have $\dfrac{s}{t} = q + \alpha$ where $\alpha = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \sqrt{-2} \in \mathbb{C}$  now my question is: how far is the distance of $|\alpha_1|$ and $|\alpha_2|$? I'm thinking $|\alpha_1|,|\alpha_2| \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$ or $|\alpha_1| \leq 1/2$ $|\alpha_2| \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$ could someone help me decide?

Comment: Don't take the largest integers $\leqslant m,n$, take the closest integers to $m,n$.

Comment: The Gaussian integers are $\, \Bbb Z + i\, \Bbb Z,\,$ not $\,\Bbb Z + \sqrt{-2}\,\Bbb Z.\,$ Are you sure you are working in the intended ring?

Comment: Yes I am, we had a previous question on $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and this question is on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]

Comment: @DanielFischer that was what I meant to write, sorry. I still don't see the answer to my question

Comment: The distance of any rational number to the nearest integer is at most $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence $N(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2\sqrt{-2}) \leqslant\;?$

Comment: @DanielFischer $N(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \sqrt{-2}) = \alpha_1 ^2 + 2\alpha_2 ^2 \leq (1/2)^2 + 2 (1/2)^2 = 3/4$?

Comment: Right. So $N(s-tq) = N(t\alpha) \leqslant \frac34 N(t)$.

Comment: @Danielfischer Right, so $N(r) = N(s-tq) \leq 3/4N(t) < N(t)$, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A small modification of your procedure will work. Let $q_1,q_2$, respectively, be the **nearest** integers to $m$ and $n$. Now the inequality goes through nicely.

Comment: if they are the nearest integers, then the way the inequality works "nicely" is if $|\alpha_1|,|\alpha_2| \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Not quite. We are looking at the norm of $t(\alpha_1+\alpha_2\sqrt{-2})$. This is the norm of $t$ times the norm of $\alpha_1+\alpha_2\sqrt{-2}$. Since $|\alpha_i|\le \frac{1}{2}$ that norm is $\le \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}(2)=\frac{3}{4}\lt 1$.